# vcenter isn't seeing open vm tools

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Centos 7 DVD is packaged with open vm tools.

But this is what I see in vCenter:
[image]

VMware actually recommends running Open VM tools.

When I tried to install vmware tools I got this message:

```
open-vm-tools are available from the OS vendor and VMware recommends using 
open-vm-tools. See http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2073803 for more information.
Do you still want to proceed with this legacy installer? [no] no
```

Am I lacking anything using open vm tools instead of vmware tools and is there a way to tell vCenter I have open vm tools installed instead of vmware tools or do I just not have to worry about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not lackng anything with open-vm-tools and will potentially avoid issues when doing kernel upgrades by upgrading open-vm-tools at the same time.

vCenter should see open-vm-tools once they are running.  Have you check to make sure the service is running after installation?

`systemctl status -l open-vm-tools`

if not running start and enable it

```
`systemctl start open-vm-tools`
`systemctl enable open-vm-tools`
```